# How to navigate to a same screen on stack in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have a stack in [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/before-you-start/). I want to navigate to a screen that is in the stack before.
but when I use `Navigation.push` command nothing happened and the screen does not change. How to implement this on react-native??

for exmaple my stakc is: [the part in the () does not navigate]

Main -> Map -> Stores (-> Map)

**Note:** I can't pop the screen to navigate to map. Because when I use the button that I Navigate with it, maybe the Map Screen doesn't in the stack. In the other word, some times I navigate from Main to Map and then to Stores, and some times I navigate to Stores from Main directly. and my button that is saying about to navigate to Stores screen in Map screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

`Navigation.push` or `Navigation.pop` is a promise that is made error when there is impossible to run command for any reason.

I use it and when `Navigation.push` made error in catch clause, I pop the screen.

For example:

```
Navigation.push('Map', {
  component: {
    id: 'Stroes',
    name: 'Stroes',
    options: {},
    passProps: {},
  },
}).catch(e => {
  Navigation.pop('Stroes');
});
```